# want to make app invite dialog for my app

Tags: facebook

anyone can help me out please. i want to make app invite dialog for my app so that i can send request to all friends i have tried it and facebook says you can create for canvas it is for game request only, i have tried that its working fine but no notifciation . so it is not useful. i want to make for my appinvite dialog.
 see example : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?api_key=1964690427084753&display=popup&frictionless=false&locale=en_US&message=Find+Friends&next=https://www.desidime.com/

please sorry if i said anything wrong at this platform not having much knowledge about languages,

Answer (score 0):

App Requests are only for sending invite to FB Desktop (Canvas) and to iOS/Android apps. No notification will appear on mobile if you don't have any iOS/Android apps.

You can combine App Requests with Feed Dialog or Feed API and this will appear as notification to your friends. App Request response will give you UserID, then using Feed.API you can send message to those friends. You need publish_actions permissions

Its not this simple as mentioned, I could share more details if you don't get what I mean.